# Angular js Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create a grid or table with multiple column filter, row edit and row select functionality. I'm new to Angular JS. I came across ng-grid, ag-grid, ui-grid and smart table. Not sure which of these are widely used and has got more online resources available in case of questions. ng-grid and ag-grid are now replaced with ui-grid?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Stackoverflow doesn't really work well when you just ask for straight up examples without any proof of effort or research.

Comment: ng-grid and ui-grid are basically same. ag-grid is much lighter, but editing is normally textboxes (for now) or you need to write cell rendering yourself.

Comment: I did try ng-grid and smart table but no luck. My data is not loading up. I just see the headers. I need to pick one to drill down and work on it. Rightnow it's hard to decide which one serves better.

Comment: use ui-grid. Documentation is not user-friendly. But when you get used to it you can do wonders.

Answer (score 3):

ui-grid and ng-grid are the same project. ng-grid changed to the name ui-grid with version three. ui-grid is angular 1.x native. ng-grid and ui-grid are written by the same group of poeple (with turnover of people) and has been going for years.

ag-grid is newer again and nothing to do with ui-grid / ng-grid. ag-grid is written by one person (Niall Crosby) and was created out of frustration using ui-grid and other grids. it's much faster, lighter, and easier to use. it's not written in angular 1.x, but native javascript, so can be used as native javascript or even in angular 2 when it comes out (ui-grid will need to be rewritten for angular 2).

the on-line documentation of ag-grid is excellent and the author is always on the on-line forum. in 2016, ag-grid will be getting many new features.